# column_spec crashing PDF in Rmd output to both PDF and html in shiny app

Tags: html, r, pdf, shiny, kableextra

EDIT: Because I had set the format options in a global function, I have to set either `latex_options` or `bootstrap_options` in the `kable_styling()` call. I was using `bootstrap_options` which wasn't being read by the latex. My work-around is to make the tables twice, once in a chunk for html, and once in a chunk for latex. Not great, but it works if I click the `Knit` button and choose `Knit to PDF`. However, it throws the original error when I try to run it in the shiny app.

---

I have created a test version (MiniTest) of my project. What I need to do is have a `shiny` app run with a tab that will produce an html file for a user-chosen (reactive) Country, and provide an Excel download (I have that working so kept it out of this example), and a PDF download. I knit in an .Rmd which chooses the format and allows for parameterization. (The shiny part was set up by someone else, from whom I took over this project when they left before finishing it.)

I use `kable` and `kableExtra` to create and format tables, as I heard it words for both html and LaTeX output. The HTML is more as less as I want it. I can knit either html or PDF, and it runs, BUT when in the shiny app, only the html portion works. I think I have narrowed down the PDF issue(s) to column_spec crashing the download. If I comment out the column_spec lines in t01 and t02, the Download PDF runs. But I need that formatting. I'm sorry, but I've lost track of all the sites I have searched.

---

In `global.R`, I set:

```
countries <- c("ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL")
```

In the .Rmd, I have YAML set up (with two-space indents for Country and output types):

params:
Country: ABC
output:
pdf_document: default
html_document: default

Relevant .Rmd chunks and inline code include:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
options(knitr.table.format = function() {
  if (knitr::is_latex_output()) "latex" else "html"
})
library(shiny) 
library(htmlwidgets) 
library(shinythemes) 
library(shinydashboard) 
library(shinyjs) 
library(shinycssloaders)
library(markdown)
library(tidyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)
library(kableExtra)
options(scipen = 999)

mini <- mtcars %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column(var = "car") %>%
  mutate(Country = c(rep("ABC", 8), rep("DEF", 8), rep("GHI", 8), rep("JKL", 8)))

## https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/font-color.html
colorize <- function(x, color) {
  if (knitr::is_latex_output()) {
    ## hack setting color='blue' instead of a hexcode with # that breaks the LaTeX code
    sprintf("\\textcolor{%s}{%s}", color = 'blue', x)    ## works, but isn't right blue
    } else if (knitr::is_html_output()) {
    sprintf("<span style='color: %s;'>%s</span>", color, x)
  } else x
}


## make two tables with `kable` and `kableExtra`
new_title <- paste0("Dynamically Changing Country Name in column", params$Country)
t01 <- mini %>% 
  filter(Country == params$Country) %>%
  select(car, mpg:hp) %>%
  rename({{new_title}} := car) %>%
  kable(align = c("l", "c", "c", "c", "c")) %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = FALSE, position = "left", bootstrap_options = c("striped", "condensed")) %>%
  column_spec(1, bold = TRUE) %>%
  column_spec(2:3, width = "5em") %>%
  row_spec(0, color = "#2A64AB") %>%
  row_spec(6, bold = TRUE)


t02_title <- paste0(params$Country, " Table with Dollar Signs in Var Names")
t02 <- mini %>%
  filter(Country == params$Country) %>%
  select(car, drat, wt) %>%
  mutate(car = case_when(car == "Mazda RX4" ~ "Mazda RX4 (US\\$)*", TRUE ~ as.character(car))) %>%
  ## want to blank out column names - removing them entirely would be best, but it fails
  kable(align = c("l", "r", "c"), escape = TRUE, col.names = c("", "", "")) %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = FALSE, position = "left", bootstrap_options = c("striped", "condensed")) %>%
  column_spec(1, bold = TRUE) %>%
  column_spec(2, width = "10em") %>%
  footnote(general = "*Never smart to start with an asterisk, but here we are", general_title = "")


## make two charts with `ggplot2`

chart1 <- mini %>%
  filter(Country == params$Country) %>%
  select(car, mpg:hp) %>%
  ggplot2::ggplot(mapping = aes(x = mpg)) +
    geom_col(aes(y = `cyl`, fill = "cyl"), color = "black")
c1_title <- paste0("Some fab title here for ", params$Country)

chart2 <- mini %>%
  filter(Country == params$Country) %>%
  select(car, vs:carb) %>%
  ggplot2::ggplot(mapping = aes(x = carb)) +
    geom_col(aes(y = `gear`, fill = "gear"), color = "black")
c2_title <- paste0("Another chart, ", params$Country)


## make a "tiny" LaTeX environment that is only generated for LaTeX output, with chunk setting `include = knitr::is_latex_output()`.
knitr::asis_output('\n\n\\begin{tiny}')

## Table 1
t01
```

I expect a PDF to pop up, but instead a Save File box pops up asking to save "DownloadPDF" with no file extension. The `ui.R` is supposed to name it as "FactCountryName.pdf" where "CountryName" is input from the Country the user chose in the drop-down list. Regardless of whether I choose Save (nothing happens) or Cancel, my R throws the following error:

**```
! LaTeX Error: Illegal character in array arg.
```**

If I comment out the line `column_spec(1, bold = TRUE) %>%`, the error changes to:

**```
! Use of \@array doesn't match its definition.
\new@ifnextchar ...served@d = #1\def \reserved@a {
                                                  #2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f...
l.74 ...m}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{5em}|c|c}
```**

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that using the `Knit` button in R automatically loads the required LaTeX packages, such as `booktabs`. Running the file in the Shiny app was not loading all the packages needed. All I had to do was specifically call the extra packages in the YAML (which I found by looking at the .tex file made from the PDF through Knit button).

```
---
params:  
  Country: ABC  
header-includes:  
- \usepackage{booktabs}
- \usepackage{longtable}
- \usepackage{array}
- \usepackage{multirow}
- \usepackage{wrapfig}
- \usepackage{float}
- \usepackage{colortbl}
- \usepackage{pdflscape}
- \usepackage{tabu}
- \usepackage{threeparttable}
- \usepackage{threeparttablex}
output:
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
  html_document: default
---
```